# Varnish behavior for no cache-control header

Tags: java, caching, varnish

I am just setting up varnish for my team. And i want to know: if my application does not currently send any `cache-control` header then what is the behavior of the varnish cache. Does it cache anyway or we need to explicitly send `cache-control` header with `max-age` value so that varnish can cache that. I have set up varnish to cache 200, 404, 400 status code response. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on a number of factors: Varnish will *not* cache any requests where the client sends a `Coookie` header, or if the server sends a response with a `Set-Cookie` header.  You also can't cache `POST` requests as they are not idempotent.

That said, if a request does *not* have cookies attached, and is a `GET` request, varnish is set to cache a request for 120s by default.  This is determined by the `default_ttl` setting in varnish, and again would only apply to requests that are cache-able in varnish (even without setting a `cache-control` header).

From the Varnish documentation:

> The Cache-Control header can contain a number of headers. Varnish evaluates it and looks for s-maxage and max-age. It will set the TTL to the value of s-maxage if found. If s-maxage isn’t found, it will use max-age. If neither exist, it will use the Expires header to set the ttl. **If none of those headers exist, it will use the default TTL**

https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_Basics.html

Comment: are you referring to the default behaviour? Configuring the VCL you are able to override any/all headers sent/received.

Comment: The question was specifically about the behavior when the application doesn't send `cache-control` headers — true that you can override any headers sent/received, but out of the box with *no* headers sent or received, there is nonetheless a default TTL for certain cache-able requests.

Comment: @JeffSisson Are you saying that without `cache-control` header from backend application (not from the client) varnish will cache?

Comment: @Trying yup, just updated the answer with a quote from the Varnish documentation

Comment: If i explicitly set the `cache-control` header to `no-cache` in the application i.e. from the backend service then varnish won't cache the response. Correct?

Comment: That's correct. `Cache-Control` responses from the server is what Varnish will listen to, and setting it to `no-cache` will mean that Varnish will not cache the response.